# Junit Test: findById method of the Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, spring-test

I am new in Junit tests and I have a question about it. Here you can see the method **findById** in my service class:

```
@Service
public class DefaultQuarterService implements QuarterService {

    private final QuarterRepository quarterRepository;

    public DefaultQuarterService(QuarterRepository quarterRepository) {
        this.quarterRepository = quarterRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public QuarterEntity findById(int id) {

        return quarterRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(String.format("Quarter does not exist for id = %s!", id)));
    }
}
```

And here is my QuarterRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface QuarterRepository extends CrudRepository<QuarterEntity, Integer> {
}
```

And here is my Junit implementation for this method:

```
@MockBean
private QuarterRepository quarterRepository;

@Test
public void throwExceptionWhenQuarterIdNotFound() {
    int id = anyInt();
    when(quarterRepository.findById(id))
            .thenReturn(Optional.empty());
    assertThatAnExceptionWasThrown(String.format("Quarter does not exist for id = %s!", id));
}

public void assertThatAnExceptionWasThrown(
        String errorMsg
) {
    expectException.expect(RuntimeException.class);
    expectException.expectMessage(errorMsg);
}
```

Unfortunately test doesn't pass. Here the error in terminal:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected test to throw (an instance of
> java.lang.RuntimeException and exception with message a string
> containing "Quarter does not exist for id = 0!")

Maybe it is so simple but I can not see what I am missing. I would be so happy if you can direct me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Here you can see the method I overrride from CrudRepository findById in my service class" - Does your service class implement CrudRepository? Can you share how you declared your service class.

Comment: @6ton Thanks for the comment. Question updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First issue**

In the `assertThatAnExceptionWasThrown` method you expect `RuntimeException` **BUT** in the service class you throw EntityNotFoundException, So I guess you should expect `EntityNotFoundException` in your test case.

**Second issue**

After this part of the code.

```java
 when(quarterRepository.findById(id))
            .thenReturn(Optional.empty());
```

Why didn't you call your service method `(findById)`?
When you are returning the empty value, you should verify your condition with the service method you want to test it.
It should be something like this.

```java
assertThatThrownBy(() -> defaultQuarterService.findById(id))
        .isInstanceOf(ApiRequestException.class)
        .hasMessageContaining("PUT_YOUR_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_HERE");
```

This is a good sample for unit-test in the spring boot. You can check it out. [**Link**](https://reflectoring.io/unit-testing-spring-boot/)

Try the above solutions and let me know it has been fixed or not. Good luck

Comment: Hello! Your suggestions helped really. I didn't add the part with assertThatThrownBy() as you suggested but I added: quarterService.findById(id) after assertThatAnExceptionWasThrown function call. Now it passes the test! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As you mock your Repository it will return with `Optional.empty()` correctly, I think you should call your service's (which is Autowired) `findById` method. It will throw the exception actually.

Comment: Hi @zip88 I added: quarterService.findById(id) after assertThatAnExceptionWasThrown function call. Now it passes the test! Thanks a lot!